# Error de foreach php

Tags: php, json

**Hola Amigos programadores es que tengo un error con un foreach cuando intento sacar datos de un archivo json será que ustedes me pueden ayudar a solucionar este error del foreach muchas Gracias anexare el codigo php estoy utilizando la libreria Http_Request2**
[image: Error del foreach]

```
 try
{   $response = $consult_fac->send();
    $res = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
    $constantes = get_defined_constants(true);
    
    $result[] = '';
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
        
    }
    return $result;
    
    
    
    
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
    return $ex;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un vardump de $res y subi la salida para ver como te esta llegando el objeto?

Comment: coloque el vardump y me aparece que el objeto esta llegando en NULL

Comment: Entonces, el problema no está en el `foreach`, sino en los datos que recibes de `$response->getBody()`, que no pueden interpretarse como JSON.

Comment: y como podria remplazar ese codigo hay para solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar la función json_decode existe la posibilidad que el JSON facilitado no tenga el formato correcto y no pueda ser decodificado.

Para comprobar que el JSON haya sido decodificado correctamente tienes que comprobar que el resultado de la función json_decode no retorne un false. En tu caso deberías retornar un array vacío en caso de que la función retorne false:

```
$res = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
/* CODIGO A COLOCAR ANTES QUE EL FOREACH: */
if($res === false) return [];
```